# How to set tabs position in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this JavaFX code with tabs. Can you tell me how I can set the position of the tabs panel to be always on the left side of the main stage:

```
VBox stackedTitledPanes = createStackedTitledPanes();

        ScrollPane scroll = makeScrollable(stackedTitledPanes);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();

        tabPane.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12pt;"); // Set global size for the font
        // Create Tabs
        Tab tabA = new Tab();
        tabA.setText("Main Component");
        tabA.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12pt;"); // Set size of the tab name
        // Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabA_stack = new StackPane();
        tabA_stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabA_stack.getChildren().add(scroll); 
        tabA.setContent(tabA_stack);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabA);

        Tab tabB = new Tab();
        tabB.setText("Second Component");
        tabB.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12pt;"); // Set size of the tab name
        // Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabB_stack = new StackPane();
        tabB_stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabB_stack.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab B"));
        tabB.setContent(tabB_stack);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabB);

        Tab tabC = new Tab();
        tabC.setText("Last Component");
        tabC.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12pt;"); // Set size of the tab name
        // Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabC_vBox = new StackPane();
        tabC_vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabC_vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab C"));
        tabC.setContent(tabC_vBox);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabC);

        mainPane.setCenter(tabPane);

        mainPane.setPrefSize(395, 580);
        mainPane.setLayoutX(850);
        mainPane.setLayoutY(32);

        scroll.setPrefSize(395, 580);
        scroll.setLayoutX(850);
        scroll.setLayoutY(32);

        root.getChildren().add(mainPane);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Sounds like you want to change your `stackedTitledPane` from a `VBox` to a `BorderPane`.
So this code:

```
VBox stackedTitledPanes = new VBox();
```

becomes:

```
BorderPane stackedTitledPanes = new BorderPane();
```

Then when you want to add your nodes, you specify which section you want to put them (I put a label in the center pane as a filler):

```
stackedTitledPanes.setLeft(mainPane);
stackedTitledPanes.setCenter(new Label("Main Content"));
```

---

**Old answer**

This will put the tabs on the left (I'm assuming this is what you're looking for):

```
    tabPane.setSide(Side.LEFT);
```

[image: TabPane Left side]

Comment: I have other in my but anyway thank you for the valuable example. My idea is to place the tab panel (with all components) always on the left side of the main stage because when I resize the main stage the position will static. I want then I resize the main stage always to see the tab panel at the left side.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting at - I've updated my answer to reflect your needs better.

Comment: Yes this works. I also tested to place the tabs panel on the right side of the main page but its not working. Is there something else that I have to change in order to place the tabs panel on the right side of the main stage?

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to use `stackedTitledPanes.setRight(mainPane);` to put the tabs on the right side.  You might need to expand the screen to see the content though (as the size of `mainPane` is 395x580 and the size of the scene is 300x250)

Comment: Is there any alternative way using `setLayoutX()` to place the component on the right side of the main stage?

Comment: You could - It'd be a bit of a pain, but you'd use a `Pane` instead of a `BorderPane`, and manually calculate the location of items using `setLayoutX()` and `setLayoutY()`.  See the javadocs if you want more detail: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setLayoutX%28double%29